# R: Reshape and expand dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

My sample dataframe in R looks the following:

```
     NAME  ID SURVEY_YEAR REFERENCE_YEAR CUMULATIVE_SUM CUMULATIVE_SUM_REFYEAR
1 NAME1  47        1960           1959             -6                      0
2 NAME1  47        1961           1960            -10                     -6
3 NAME1  47        1963           1961             NA                     NA
4 NAME1  47        1965           1963            -23                    -10
5 NAME2 259        2007           2004             -9                      0
6 NAME2 259        2009           2007             NA                     NA
7 NAME2 259        2010           2009             NA                     NA
8 NAME2 259        2011           2010             NA                     NA
9 NAME2 259        2014           2011            -40                     -9
```

What I am trying to do is to rearrange the dataframe in the following way.

```
NAME    ID  time            YEAR    CUMULATIVE_SUM  id
NAME1   47  REFERENCE_YEAR  1959    0               1
NAME1   47  SURVEY_YEAR     1960    -6              1
NAME1   47  REFERENCE_YEAR  1960    -6              2
NAME1   47  SURVEY_YEAR     1961    -10             2
NAME1   47  REFERENCE_YEAR  1961    NA              3
NAME1   47  SURVEY_YEAR     1963    NA              3
NAME1   47  REFERENCE_YEAR  1963    -10             4
NAME1   47  SURVEY_YEAR     1965    -23             4
NAME2   259 REFERENCE_YEAR  2004    0               5
NAME2   259 SURVEY_YEAR     2007    -9              5
NAME2   259 REFERENCE_YEAR  2007    NA              6
NAME2   259 SURVEY_YEAR     2009    NA              6
NAME2   259 REFERENCE_YEAR  2009    NA              7
NAME2   259 SURVEY_YEAR     2010    NA              7
NAME2   259 REFERENCE_YEAR  2010    NA              8
NAME2   259 SURVEY_YEAR     2011    NA              8
NAME2   259 REFERENCE_YEAR  2011    -9              9
NAME2   259 SURVEY_YEAR     2014    -40             9
```

I am trying to do this the following way but this is not exactly what I want.

```
# read in data
data <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1", "NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2"),
                   ID=c(47,47,47,47,259,259,259,259,259),
                   SURVEY_YEAR=c(1960,1961,1963,1965,2007,2009,2010,2011,2014), 
                   REFERENCE_YEAR=c(1959,1960,1961,1963,2004,2007,2009,2010,2011),
                   CUMULATIVE_SUM=c(-6,-10,NA,-23,-9,NA,NA,NA,-40),
                   CUMULATIVE_SUM_REFYEAR=c(0,-6,NA,-10,0,NA,NA,NA,-9))  

# reshape data  
dat3 <- reshape(data, direction="long",
                    varying = list(c("SURVEY_YEAR","REFERENCE_YEAR"), c("CUMULATIVE_SUM","CUMULATIVE_SUM_REFYEAR")), 
                    v.names=c("YEAR","CUMULATIVE_SUM"), times = c("SURVEY_YEAR", "REFERENCE_YEAR"))
```

Does anyone have an idea how to reshape the dataframe correctly so that it corresponds to the desired solution above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reorder the data you already have

```
dat3 <- dat3[with(dat3, order(NAME, ID, YEAR, id)), ]
```

Or if you want high performance

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(dat3), NAME, ID, YEAR, id)
```

Comment: chose your high performance example david and it works like a charm! thank you and all the others who contributed!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
data["id"]<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

sursub<-data # make subset
refsub<-data # make subset

sursub["time"]<-"SURVEY_YEAR" #add column 
sursub["REFERENCE_YEAR"]<- 0 #remove reference_year

refsub["time"]<-  "REFERENCE_YEAR" #add column
refsub["SURVEY_YEAR"]<- 0 #remove survey_year

merge<-rbind(sursub, refsub) #merge two subsets back together

sorted<- merge[with(merge, order(id)), ] #sort based on id column
sorted["year"]<-sorted[,3]+sorted[,4] #make year column with the observation year
```

It is then just a matter of  removing the unneeded columns.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr) 
 data%>% 
 gather(time, YEAR, 3:4)%>% 
 mutate(CUMULATIVE_SUM=ifelse(time=="SURVEY_YEAR", CUMULATIVE_SUM, CUMULATIVE_SUM_REFYEAR)) %>%
 arrange(NAME, ID, YEAR, row_number()) %>%
 select(c(1:2, 5:6,3)) %>%
 head(4)
 #      NAME ID           time YEAR CUMULATIVE_SUM
 #1 NAME1 47 REFERENCE_YEAR 1959              0
 #2 NAME1 47    SURVEY_YEAR 1960             -6
 #3 NAME1 47 REFERENCE_YEAR 1960             -6
 #4 NAME1 47    SURVEY_YEAR 1961            -10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ddf2 = data.frame(NAME=character(), ID=numeric(), time=character(), YEAR=numeric(), CUMULATIVE_SUM=numeric(), id=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=F)
for (r in 1:nrow(data)){
    ddf2[nrow(ddf2)+1,]=c(as.character(data[r,1]), data[r,2], "REFERENCE_YEAR", data[r,4], data[r,6], rownames(data)[r] )
    ddf2[nrow(ddf2)+1,]=c(as.character(data[r,1]), data[r,2], "SURVEY_YEAR", data[r,3], data[r,5], rownames(data)[r] )
}

ddf2
    NAME  ID           time YEAR CUMULATIVE_SUM id
1  NAME1  47 REFERENCE_YEAR 1959              0  1
2  NAME1  47    SURVEY_YEAR 1960             -6  1
3  NAME1  47 REFERENCE_YEAR 1960             -6  2
4  NAME1  47    SURVEY_YEAR 1961            -10  2
5  NAME1  47 REFERENCE_YEAR 1961           <NA>  3
6  NAME1  47    SURVEY_YEAR 1963           <NA>  3
7  NAME1  47 REFERENCE_YEAR 1963            -10  4
8  NAME1  47    SURVEY_YEAR 1965            -23  4
9  NAME2 259 REFERENCE_YEAR 2004              0  5
10 NAME2 259    SURVEY_YEAR 2007             -9  5
11 NAME2 259 REFERENCE_YEAR 2007           <NA>  6
12 NAME2 259    SURVEY_YEAR 2009           <NA>  6
13 NAME2 259 REFERENCE_YEAR 2009           <NA>  7
14 NAME2 259    SURVEY_YEAR 2010           <NA>  7
15 NAME2 259 REFERENCE_YEAR 2010           <NA>  8
16 NAME2 259    SURVEY_YEAR 2011           <NA>  8
17 NAME2 259 REFERENCE_YEAR 2011             -9  9
18 NAME2 259    SURVEY_YEAR 2014            -40  9
```

Comment: The CUMULATIVE_SUM column is not `numeric` in your result `class(ddf2$CUMULATIVE_SUM)#[1] "character"`

Comment: I do not know why all columns are getting converted to characters even though I have specified in data frame creation for some to be numeric. If it is important, as.numeric() etc will have to be added in the 'for' loop assignment statements. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mso I think you have to specify in the `options`.  or may be use `data.frame` instead of `c`.  Not tested though.